# Convert struct array to numeric or double array

Tags: matlab

Can someone help me. What I need to do if I want to convert a struct array to double or complex double to double because i need to use it as input for svm classifier.Thanks in advanced .

Comment: Please show us your code so far...

Comment: i already combined 7 patients that contain 19 feature extraction each one.. the data in 7x1 struct with 19 field ..when i using in SVM     clc;clear all;close all;
load trainset.mat
data =new_var;
group = label;
SVMStruct = svmtrain(data,group,'kernel_function','linear');
species = svmclassify(SVMStruct,meas,'showplot',false);                              the error will be   Error using svmtrain (line 241)
TRAINING must be a numeric matrix.    i know that i need to convert the struct array into double but dont know how? can u help me

Comment: It's much more helpful if you add your code to the initial question with proper formatting. Reading it out of the comments is...difficult. It would probably also help to see a small extract of the structure that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data struct looks like this (with 7 patients, 19 features and 150 feature vectors for each patient):

```
data = 

    p1: [150x19 double]
    p2: [150x19 double]
    p3: [150x19 double]
    p4: [150x19 double]
    p5: [150x19 double]
    p6: [150x19 double]
    p7: [150x19 double]
```

and you want to concatenate them into one big matrix (you will not distinguish between patients when training your SVM) of the form `1050x19 double`, then the following code snippet will do the trick:

```
% Generate test data
data.p1(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p2(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p3(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p4(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p5(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p6(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);
data.p7(:,1:19) = randn(150,19);

% Add each patient features to cell array
data_cell = cellfun(@(field) data.(field), fieldnames(data), 'UniformOutput', false);

% Vertically concatenate the entries in the cell array from above 
data_combined = vertcat(data_cell{:}); %1050x19 double
```

You will need to concatenate your `group` labels in a similar way as well, making sure you don't loose track of which group label corresponds to which feature vector in your combined data.

Best of luck

Comment: thanks but what is feature vector? I have 7x1 struct with 19 field , which one i should assume as feature vector?